# Internal Rxjs error during nestjs grpc request using client-streaming

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, grpc, rxjs-observables

I'm using a nestjs backend that receives gRPC calls with client-side streaming and I've encountered a very odd issue:
When **many** gRPC requests are made to the server from a client, and the client crashes/exits mid-way, then that causes the server to crash as well.
The error however is not coherent and appears to be an internal rxjs error.

Basically, my backend controller receives an rxjs Observable of data, which I subscribe on and process. After the subscription, I await the `lastValueFrom` result of said Observable. Then the server returns a message to the client. I'll supply some sample code and the error below:

Code:

```
@GrpcStreamMethod('MyService', 'MyCallName')
  async myCallHandler(
    messages: Observable<RequestClass>,
  ): Promise<ResponseClass> {
    let errorsOccured = false;

    const subscription: Subscription = messages
      .pipe(catchError((err) => of()))
      .subscribe({
        next: async (msg) => {

          try {
            await this.myService.process(msg);
          } catch (err) {
            errorsOccured = true;
          }
        },
        error: (err) => {
          errorsOccured = true;
          const stack: string | undefined = (<Error>err)?.stack;
        },
      });

    let lastValue = undefined;
    try {
      lastValue = await lastValueFrom(messages);
    } catch (err) {
      if (!(err instanceof EmptyError)) {
        errorsOccured = true;
      }
    }

    subscription.unsubscribe();

    return {
      code: `${errorsOccured ? 'E' : 'S'}_GEN_00001`,
    };
  }
```

Error:

```
/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/createErrorClass.ts:13
    instance.stack = new Error().stack;
                     ^
Error: 
    at _super (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/createErrorClass.ts:13:22)
    at new EmptyErrorImpl (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/EmptyError.ts:26:3)
    at Object.complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts:71:18)
    at ConsumerObserver.complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:185:25)
    at SafeSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:132:24)
    at SafeSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:106:12)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:132:24)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:106:12)
    at /home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/takeUntil.ts:48:89
    at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/ioch/unucare/lnp/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.ts:70:13)
```

I fail to understand what is causing this error.